# It's possible combinate augeas & template?

Tags: templates, puppet, augeas

It's possible combinate augeas & template?. The objective its a static part of test inside a file an another variable with the augeas. 
I'm reading the documentation and examples but I think its not possible.
If its possible, can you put an example?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you manage a file with the `file` type, you need to manage it entirely and you cannot manage parts of it with another type, such as `augeas`. In order to manage files by parts, you may want to consider using one of the concat modules instead (Puppet Labs' or Onyxpoint's)

Comment: yes, but I need maintain the file because any persorn change this file

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: do you want to manage the whole file in order to prevent local changes, or do you want to allow local changes?

Comment: The objective its modify the file with puppet and prevent the changes from other users. With Augeas I can modify the file if user delete the parameters introduced with augeas, puppet writte again, but the user writea new line for exemple, puppet don't delete it.

Comment: Ok, so you need to manage the file entirely. The possible approaches are: a `file` resource with a template; a `concat` resource (either Puppet Labs' or OnyxPoint's) or a native type (see augeasproviders.com for example) with purging (using the `resources` resouce type).